# How do i convert a string that was changed to a different radix in java

Tags: java, biginteger, radix

I have a string whose radix has been changed & its value is printed. Is there a way to convert the string back to its original form?

My code looks like:

```
String b=text2[i].toString(16);
```

Here `text2` array is of `BigInteger` type. I want to get the original string from variable `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new BigInteger(b, 16).toString();
```

## Sample program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final BigInteger original = new BigInteger("27");
    final String converted = original.toString(16);
    final BigInteger convertedBack = new BigInteger(converted, 16);

    System.out.println("original = [" + original.toString() + "]");
    System.out.println("converted = [" + converted + "]");
    System.out.println("convertedBack = [" + convertedBack.toString() + "]");
}
```

## Output:

```
original = [27]
converted = [1b]
convertedBack = [27]
```

Comment: Thanks but it works only with numbers not with characters such as a,b @Smutje

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say - which part of my example program does not work at your machine?

Comment: I replaced the value "27" used for original variable and replaced it with "123A" and it show me error @Smutje

Comment: And how do you think should "123A" be interpreted as decimal?

Comment: Oops,,my fault .Actually I am making a simple RSA encryption& decryption program ,the Encryption side sends the String in the radix 16.But the decryption side works with radix 10 only .Also the    string from the encrption side contains alphabets also .plz help @Smutje